# Android Uploading Camera Image, Video to Server with Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-studio

[Source code and project link description here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/)

Facing the error, dont know how to fix - I am getting error on MainActivity.java and UploadActivity.java.I have tried many work around and nothing helps

```
09-20 18:06:37.279 21398-21398/info.androidhive.camerafileupload E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: info.androidhive.camerafileupload, PID: 21398
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.camerafileupload/info.androidhive.camerafileupload.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at info.androidhive.camerafileupload.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error stack trace tells you:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
```

So the problem is that when you do:

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.color.action_bar))));
```

the call to getActionBar() returns null.

There are a number of reasons why getActionBar() might return null, but the most common one is that you should be calling

```
getSupportActionBar()
```

instead of

```
getActionBar()
```

So try replacing all instances of "getActionBar()" in your code with "getSupportActionBar()"